# Excel VBA faster way to parse a Json

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following snippet of code that calls a Rest API and pulls a JSON that has approximately a 1000 records of 50 fields. This code works but has a load time of over 20 seconds. This is 1 of six that I have to get. I use JSON Converter ' VBA-JSON v2.3.1
' (c) Tim Hall - https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON. Is there a faster way?

```
base_url = "https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/"

endpoint = "category.json """

url = base_url & endpoint

Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

xmlhttp.Open "GET", url, False, M8Username, M8Password

xmlhttp.Send

If xmlhttp.Status = 200 Then

    Set jsontext = JsonConverter.ParseJson(xmlhttp.ResponseText)
    
Ws2.Rows.ClearContents

    For Each Collect In jsontext
        With Ws2
            For Each key In Collect.Keys
            On Error Resume Next
                .Cells(1, k).value = key
                .Cells(j, k).value = Collect.Item(key)
                k = k + 1
            Next key
            k = 1
            j = j + 1
        End With
    Next Collect
    j = 2
    k = 1
    
Else
    Debug.Print "An error occurred:" & xmlhttp.Status
    Exit Sub
End If

Set xmlhttp = Nothing
```

````
Here is a sample Record
```lang-json
{"uuid":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","active":1,"date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","job_address":"AAAAAA,\nAAAAA, AA 00000","billing_address":"0000 AAAAA\nAAAAA, AA 00000","status":"Quote","quote_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","work_order_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","work_done_description":"","generated_job_id":"6679","completion_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","completion_actioned_by_uuid":"","unsuccessful_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","payment_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","payment_method":"","payment_amount":0,"payment_actioned_by_uuid":"","edit_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","payment_note":"","ready_to_invoice":"0","ready_to_invoice_stamp
":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","company_uuid":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","geo_is_valid":1,"lng":-00.0000000,"lat":00.0000000,"geo_country":"United States","geo_postcode":"00000","geo_state":"AA","geo_city":"AAAAAAAAAA","geo_street":"AAAAA","geo_number":"0000","payment_processed":0,"payment_processed_stamp":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","payment_received":1,"payment_received_stamp":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","total_invoice_amount":"0.0000","job_is_scheduled_until_stamp":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","category_uuid":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","queue_uuid":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","queue_expiry_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","badges":"[\"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001\",\"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002\",\"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000003\"]","invoice_sent":false,"purchase_order_number":"","invoice_sent_stamp":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","queue_assigned_staff_uuid":"","quote_sent_stamp":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","quote_sent":false,"active_network_request_uuid":"","related_knowledge_articles":false,"job_description":"AA AAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAA","created_by_staff_uuid":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"}
````

Comment: Need some idea of which part(s) of the process are taking the most time.  Try using `Timer` (`Dim t: t = Timer` at start) and adding some outputs (eg) `Debug.Print "Fetch complete", Timer-t` after the `xmlhttp.Send`

Comment: It is the `for each collect` loop. This rest of it takes less than a second.

Answer (score 2):

You can try writing the results to an array first.
(untested)

This assumes every dictionary in the top-level collection has the same keys, in the same order (which might not be very robust in the long term...)

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim base_url, endpoint, URL, XMLHTTP As Object, jsontext As Object, arr(), k
    Dim d As Object, M8Username, M8Password, Ws2 As Worksheet, j As Long, n As Long, tmp as Object
    
    base_url = "https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/"
    endpoint = "category.json """
    URL = base_url & endpoint
    
    Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
    XMLHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False, M8Username, M8Password
    
    XMLHTTP.Send
    
    If XMLHTTP.status = 200 Then
    
        Set jsontext = JsonConverter.ParseJson(XMLHTTP.responseText)
        Set d = jsontext(1) 'assuming top-level object is a collection?
        
        Set Ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data") 'for example
        Ws2.Cells.ClearContents
        ReDim arr(1 To jsontext.Count + 1, 1 To d.Count) 'size output array
        
        'populate the headers
        For j = 1 To d.Count '# of keys
            arr(1, j) = d.Keys()(j-1) 'Keys is zero-based
        Next j
        
        For n = 1 To jsontext.Count  'loop over the collection
            Set d = jsontext(n)      'next dict
            j = 0
            For Each k In d
                j = j + 1
                If k = "badges" Then '<<< handle special case...
                    Set tmp = JsonConverter.ParseJson(d(k)) 'convert to collection
                    arr(n + 1, j) = CollectionToString(tmp) 'convert to string list
                Else
                    arr(n + 1, j) = d(k) 'n+1 because first row has headers
                End If
            Next k
        Next n
        Ws2.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr 'put the data on the sheet
    Else
        Debug.Print "An error occurred:" & XMLHTTP.status
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Set XMLHTTP = Nothing
End Sub

Function CollectionToString(col As Collection)
    Dim s As String, sep As String, el
    For Each el In col
        s = s & sep & el
        sep = ","
    Next el
    CollectionToString = s
End Function
```

Comment: I tried this on a couple of them and it did not make any discernable difference.

Comment: Difficult to suggest any other approaches without an example JSON response.

Comment: I would love to send you one but it has PPI in it so that is not possible.

Comment: So replace the PPI ?  It's only the approx size/structure which matters, not the content.

Comment: You are speaking Ancient Greek to me. I just looked at my first JSON a couple weeks ago.

Comment: One sample record from your JSON (where a record is the part between `{}`), with the sensitive part(s) replaced with dummy text would be plenty.  Also would be useful to show your timings from the original code.

Comment: I tested this on a JSON file (saved to my local drive) with 1000 records, each with 50 fields.  It took about 3 sec to read and parse the JSON, and then another 3 sec to populate the JSON content onto the sheet.

Comment: ...using your original code took about 15 sec to populate the worksheet after parsing the JSON content.

Comment: I have added one of the JSON records above. My biggest issue and why I am trying to find a fast way is that there is 2 other Rest API's I need to pull that are a lot larger, 14k & 9k. When I run all of them it takes 123 seconds to process. Way to slow to be practical. I currently have the runtime at 17 seconds for all 6 JSONs, the other 5 JSONs are only 5-30 records so are much smaller.

Comment: Tim Williams you have been helping on another question "Excel VBA - Issues with Match and LookupDict". These two are actually tied together if you can help me with another issue here. When you look at the Badges Key it has a 3rd level to the JSON that I haven't figured out how to handle so I skipped it creating the other question. If you can help me parse a 3D JSON so that it parses the Badges also my other question will become a simple `split(string,",")`. I tried multiple attempts of `IF key = Badges` run it back through the JSON Converter for a second time but failed miserably.

Comment: Better to edit your own question if you want to add content - I moved your sample there.

Comment: See edits above - looks like the "badges" value is a stringified JSON object, so you need to parse that to a collection before you can extract the values (or use a regex-based approach as in your other question)